# How to bind TextView to a dynamic variable?

Tags: android

I want to show a grid of `TextView` items. Each one shows as text how often the item was clicked. On each tap the value should increase by +1.

Question: how can I properly bind the counter value for it on each item?

```
//show simple grid with textview items, each showing how many times each was clicked
GridView grid;

final List<AtomicInteger> items = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      items.add(new AtomicInteger(0)); //initialize with count=0
}
grid.setAdapter(MyItemAdapter(items));

grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        items.get(position).incrementAndGet();
        //TODO how to populate this to the TextView?
    }
});
```

How can I write the new count to the `TextView`, so that the display is updated?

And is it correct at all to pass the counter list to the adapter, and also increment it inside the clicklistener?

Or should I rather add a clicklistener onto the `MyItemAdapter` inside the class itself?

Comment: [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) should redraw your view (call it after incrementing the variable). Why do you need `AtomicInteger` ?

Comment: But the notify would cause a redraw the complete view? That's bad, I'd just would want to redraw the item whose counter was changed. I'm using `AtomicInteger` for not having to call the setter, but just invoke the increment on the getter.

Comment: AdapterView<?> parent contains all the views find the view based on the position.. Check the my answer

Answer (score 0):

Parent variable contains all the items on the grid view.
You can find the clicked item by

```
 ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(position)).setText(String.valueOf(count));
```

This updates only the clicked item in the grid view

**EDIT**:
If you have setup custom item layout for grid items,

```
View itemParent = parent.getChildAt(position);
((TextView) itemParent.findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id)).setText("count")
```

Comment: `parent.getChildAt(position)` returns a `RelativeLayout` in my case. Because the clicklistener is attached to the `GridView` class, and the items are inside that grid.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. That works, though it feels a bit strange not being able to get the clicked component itself in a listener that is directly attached to the component. But if that's the preferred way, ok.

Comment: It would've been lot easier if you were using a recycler view with grid layout manager.

Comment: I see. But RecyclerView seems to be designed for showing ranges of large lists. I always want to display my full item content of the list.